# playframework form mapping date and time

Tags: forms, date, playframework, mapping

I have a case class that looks like this (DateTime is the org.joda.time.DateTime one) :

```
case class Match (  
  var date: DateTime,
  var tournament: Option[String] = None,
  var _links: Link
)
```

For my JSon Rest Service I mapped it like this :

```
  implicit val matchReader: Reads[Match] = (
    (JsPath \ "date").read[DateTime] and
    (JsPath \ "tournament").readNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "_links").read[Link]
  )(Match.apply _)

  implicit val matchWriter: Writes[Match] = (
    (JsPath \ "date").write[DateTime] and
    (JsPath \ "tournament").writeNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "_links").write[Link]
  )(unlift(Match.unapply))
```

While for my Form I mapped it like this :

```
  val matchMapping = mapping(
      "date" -> jodaDate,
      "tournament" -> optional(text),
      "_links"   -> linkMapping
    )(Match.apply)(Match.unapply)
```

But my boss wants me to display two separated fields on the form, one to for the Date and the other one for the Time, but to keep storing the value in a single member of my case class because it represents the output objet for the Rest Service to store the data in the DB.

How can I do that ?

Thanks